# Replace values in xml using ANT

Tags: ant, xml-parsing

I want to replace the ProductVersion value at <DefineConstants> node of the following xml. Remaining part of the line has to be preserved. 
Example:

```
<DefineConstants>XXXXX;ProductVersion=20.323.23;YYYYY</DefineConstants>
```

to

```
<DefineConstants>XXXXX;ProductVersion=21.58.44;YYYYY</DefineConstants>
```

I tried the `replaceregexp` but it changes the remaining contents.

```
<replaceregexp file="${basedir}\Installer.wixproj"
     match="ProductVersion=([0-9].*);(.*)"
     replace="ProductVersion=${SpaceVersion};\1"
     byline="true"
/>
```

Could you guide me what i am doing wrong in this.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
   <PropertyGroup>
      <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
      <ProductVersion>3.5</ProductVersion>
      <ProjectGuid>{6bc0a85b-9c15-41e6-874b-5fe07e5338e6}</ProjectGuid>
      <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
      <OutputName>Installer</OutputName>
      <OutputType>Package</OutputType>
      <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' AND '$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)' != '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
      <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
      <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
      <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
      <DefineConstants>Debug;</DefineConstants>
      <WixVariables>
      </WixVariables>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
      <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
      <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
      <DefineConstants>SourceDir=$(SolutionDir)XSSE\;ProductVersion=3.3.1.75;ProductName=XSSE;ToolchinShortcut=XSSEToolchinShortcut;ExtensionDir=XSSE;ManifestFileName=extension.vsixmanifest;PkageDefFileName=XSSE.ToolchainProvider.pkgdef;REGKEY=Software\Microsoft\XSSE;</DefineConstants>
      <WixVariables>XYZ=123;</WixVariables>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="filefragment.wxs" />
      <Compile Include="Product.wxs" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
      <WixExtension Include="WixUIExtension">
         <HintPath>$(WixExtDir)\WixUIExtension.dll</HintPath>
         <Name>WixUIExtension</Name>
      </WixExtension>
   </ItemGroup>
   <Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think trying to capture the remainder of the line after the product version is unnecessary.

You don't need to worry about that. If your regex leaves the rest of the text alone, you can just replace the ProductVersion only.

I had success with this:

```
<replaceregexp file="${basedir}\Installer.wixproj"
    match="ProductVersion=[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+\.?;"
    replace="ProductVersion=${SpaceVersion};"
    byline="true"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `\2` instead of `\1`.

```
<replaceregexp file="${basedir}\Installer.wixproj"
       match="ProductVersion=([0-9].*);(.*)"
       replace="ProductVersion=${SpaceVersion};\2"
       byline="true"
        />
```

Standalone test:

```
<project default="test">

    <property name="SpaceVersion" value="a.b.c"/>

    <target name="test">
      <replaceregexp file="test.xml"
         match="ProductVersion=([0-9].*);(.*)"
         replace="ProductVersion=${SpaceVersion};\2"
         byline="true"
       />
    </target>
</project>
```

Comparison of changed file with original:

```
$diff test.xml test.xml.0
2c2
<     <DefineConstants>XXXXX;ProductVersion=a.b.c;YYYYY</DefineConstants>
---
>     <DefineConstants>XXXXX;ProductVersion=20.323.23;YYYYY</DefineConstants>
```

Comment: It removes the YYYY part of that line.

Expected Output:
<DefineConstants>XXXXX;ProductVersion=21.58.44;YYYYY</DefineConstants>
Actual Output:
<DefineConstants>XXXXX;ProductVersion=21.58.44;</DefineConstants>

Comment: No it doesn't. Not after you change `\1` to `\2`.